# Autofocus in Windows Phone 7 Camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera, autofocus

I am writing an WP7 app that use camera to capture and process images. One of the critical requirement for the images is to always be focused. Unfortunately, the WP7 [doesn't support autofocus](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/103150/611303.aspx). And by **autofocus** I mean the capability to always focus to a certain point on the screen.

Can anyone recommend a way to have enable or implement that feature?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a DispatcherTimer that will keep calling FocusAtPoint on ticks, using a point in the viewfinder?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera.focusatpoint(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work well because at the selected points in time the camera would focus even if it is already focused. And with the Lumia phone I have the focus action takes 1 second, during which it would zoom in and zoom out before finding the right focus. Hence the user experience is really bad.